# When running the simulator in latest xcode (4.4) for iphone the button goes out of the screen

Tags: xcode, button, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, visible

[image]

I have just started learning xcode and I am in the first step. I am following head first book. there are no xib files now like in that book but storyboard views.

I add a basic button and label and run the simulator. Th button is going out of the screen view of the iphone simulator.

Why the screen resolution is different when I selected the iphone interface? Its much bigger than the area visible on the simulator.

Why the button is going out of screen instead of center?

Comment: It's tough to answer this question without see how you set up the storyboard view.

Comment: ok uploading an image, if I put it on top left of storyboard then its centre of the simulator, if I put it in center of the storyboard then it goes out of the simulator view.

Comment: here is the link  http://i.stack.imgur.com/QN5x8.jpg

Comment: Is that the iPad storyboard?  The view is so large in the storyboard editor.

Comment: No its the iphone one, that is the problem. I am very new to it  and have no idea how to change the storyboard size.